# Determining surface that reflectance curve matches?

Tags: remote-sensing, reflectance, surface

I was wondering to what surface that reflectance curve belongs?

It is definitely no water or snow since their reflectance drops at a much smaller wavelength.

I was thinking about a dense cloud but the decrease seems to be too constant.

[image]

Comment: Strange that it doesn't have the water absorption "dips". Any hints on where it came from?

Comment: Nope, its a part of an exercise where I could easily assign all the respective curves, thats the only one where I have no clue.

Comment: its something white

Comment: @nickves It definitely is

Comment: Any idea on what type of remotely sensed data this spectral signature was derived from (e.g. satellite imagery, hand-held spectrometer)?  I am not seeing any absorption bands, so data was probably acquired on the ground.  My guess is snow of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for what object this particular spectral signature ties at but i can suggest to browse a spectral library for something that is close match.

http://speclib.jpl.nasa.gov/

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that it must be some kind of cloud, since its the only object that I could find that declines in such a constant way after peaking at the visible wavelength spectrum.

Answer (score -1):

Spectral reflectance curve is the graphical representation of spatial response of an object on different wavelengths of electromagnetic spectrum